# What is appropriate way to install ruby on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

I have a computer serves as a server. I have bitnami-gitlab stack on it. And now I want to install my rails app to this server. The thing confuses me, bitnami-gitlab has ruby interpreter and other apps (rails , gem, bundler etc.). Gitlab application uses git user on ubuntu. When I type;

```
sudo su git
which ruby
```

It gives me the directory of ruby which is inside of bitnami installation directory. Now, I want to install ruby, rails, apache and passenger to deploy my rails app. What is the appropriate way to do? I want to start my rails app as boot time. Should I install ruby to root user or my own user? 
When I install ruby, will my gitlab application crahs?

Comment: To avoid mess, install ruby using `rvm`. Its a good way to manage ruby and its versions. By using `rvm`, ruby remains in a sandbox without conflicting with other ruby applications installed outside `rvm`. Install all the dependencies first to make your installation smooth. At the end install `rvm` with a ruby version, apache and passenger.

Comment: @HarryBomrah , which user own the ruby when I install via rvm?

Comment: Well its on you. You can install rvm under ur user if you make sure the application will be in your user's home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I do it >

First, update apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then if you do not have it install Curl, for installing RVM

```
 sudo apt-get install curl
```

Then run the appropriate RVM install there are multiple options like added rails, puma JRuby etc. check RVM website for more info. For just ruby run >

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Now exit the shell session and start a new one

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

RVM has its own requirements that can be auto installed by running >

```
rvm requirements
```

Now managing you ruby environments is easy and you can have multiple versions without making a mess.

To install any ruby version you need just run (x.x.x) version of the ruby>

```
rvm install x.x.x
```

To list versions you have installed run >

```
rvm list
```

Note also that now you can specify in your GEMFILE what version to use. Simply add `ruby 'x.x.x'` and rvm uses the version you specified as long as its already installed. Not having it raises error.

Comment: It is really important that you make sure none of the debian ruby or ruby-rvm packages are installed before following these steps.  If they were make sure to uninstall them all with the apt-get --purge option. sudo apt-get remove ruby-rvm --purge

Comment: Thank you Kimmo, I followed this [1] guide that similiar to your answer. Seems the best way.

[1] http://renaud-cuny.com/en/blog/2013-04-11-step-by-step-ruby-rvm-installation-ubuntu-server/

Comment: Seems about right. I think keypoint there is to have RVM to avoid Gem conflicts